# UnauthorizedOperation when calling the CreateSnapshot operation from AWS Lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

> **An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the CreateSnapshot operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: jL5ZYRDd52Y_Xpt7xet7GIyJZkUpGhgJGwCsg

- `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` AWS managed: Provides write permissions to CloudWatch Logs.
- `s3-read-and-write-policy`    Customer inline
- `ebs-cloudtrail-read-policy`  Customer inline
- `ebs-ssm-read-write-policy`   Customer inline
- `ebs-volume-and-snapshot-read-policy`

```py
def createEBSSnapshots(volumes_to_delete,ec2Client,ssmClient):
    print('Initiating create snapshot requests')
    for volume in volumes_to_delete:
        # TODO: write code...
        print('Creating snapshot for ',volume)
        today = str(date.today())
        # print("Today's date:", today)
        ec2Client.create_snapshot(
                Description='This snapshot is generated for volume which was not utilized since last '+str(timeWindowDeleteVol)+' hours.',
                # OutpostArn='string',
                VolumeId=volume,
                TagSpecifications=[
                    {
                        'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
                        'Tags': [
                            {
                                'Key': 'unusedEBSSnapshot',
                                'Value': 'true'
                            },
                            {
                                'Key': 'unusedVolumeID',
                                'Value': volume
                             },
                             {
                                'Key': 'creationDate',
                                'Value': today
                             },
                        ]
                    },
                ],
                # DryRun=True
        )
```

Comment: Please Edit your Question to show the permissions in the IAM Role associated with your AWS Lambda function and the code that is calling `CreateSnapshot`.

Comment: What is the contents of your `ebs-volume-and-snapshot-read-policy`? It sounds like that is the policy that _should_ be granting the necessary permissions.